# Jboss Failover support without load balancing

Tags: java, jboss, failover

I have two Jboss instances installed on different servers. My aim is to manage a failover recovery between these Jboss instances. Load  balancing is not needed. This is customer requirement. Normally client is connected to JBoss 1, perform a failover, and which the client will automatically connect to JBoss 2.

As I said  I want to serve only one Jboss instance at a time.

Actually I have a solution, but I don't know if it works. My aim was to write a service that checks if Jboss is running. When I catch a failover, I  want to change jndi.properties of client, then other Jboss instance will start to serve client request. But I do not know this solution works. Also Jboss can provide me a service( or other property) to check a specific instance is running?

Do you think my solution can work? Or How can I do this? Do I have to install Apache ? Apache provides failover without load balancing.

Comment: What version of JBoss?

Comment: The version is Jboss AS6